# How do I show the following integral inequality?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

I have the next exercise.

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that $\int_{0}^{1}f^2(t)dt\geq(\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt)^2$.

I know it can be done using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, but can is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: You can use Jensen's inequality.

Comment: you can use also the Hölder inequality, where the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be seen as a particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that for any real $x$,
$$0\leq \int_{0}^{1}(x+f(t))^2dt=x^2+2x\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt+\int_{0}^{1}f^2(t)dt$$
Now let $x=-\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$.

Comment: why is that integral positive?

Comment: It is the integral of a non negative function (a function squared).

Comment: Ok I think it works but just let me know how did you get this idea?

Comment: @OvyOvy Start with a "trivial" (integral) inequality with a parameter and then play with the parameter is common strategy for this kind of stuff. See for example here for a similar approach: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492294/how-prove-this-integral-inequality?rq=1